# GWT Error - Unable to see output in Browser using DocLayoutPanel

Tags: java, gwt, jakarta-ee

I am writing a application using DocLayout Panel. The problem is that I can see the result in the GWT designer but the same output is not appearing when I am trying to run the application. Can anyone tell me why this is happening.[image]

My code is as follows:

```
package com.ibm.projects.quest.qwt.gui;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;

public class ApplicationDefaultWindow extends DockLayoutPanel {
    private FooterPanel footerPanel = null;
    private HeaderPanel headerPanel = null;
    private LeftNavigation leftNavigation = null;
    private RightNavigation rightNavigation = null;
    private ContentPanel centerPanel = null;

    public FooterPanel getFooterPanel() {
        return footerPanel;
    }

    public void setFooterPanel(FooterPanel footerPanel) {
        this.footerPanel = footerPanel;
    }

    public HeaderPanel getHeaderPanel() {
        return headerPanel;
    }

    public void setHeaderPanel(HeaderPanel headerPanel) {
        this.headerPanel = headerPanel;
    }

    public LeftNavigation getLeftNavigation() {
        return leftNavigation;
    }

    public void setLeftNavigation(LeftNavigation leftNavigation) {
        this.leftNavigation = leftNavigation;
    }

    public RightNavigation getRightNavigation() {
        return rightNavigation;
    }

    public void setRightNavigation(RightNavigation rightNavigation) {
        this.rightNavigation = rightNavigation;
    }

    public ContentPanel getCenterPanel() {
        return centerPanel;
    }

    public void setCenterPanel(ContentPanel centerPanel) {
        this.centerPanel = centerPanel;
    }

    public ApplicationDefaultWindow() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(Unit.EM);
        headerPanel= new HeaderPanel();
        this.addNorth(headerPanel, 7.1);        
        leftNavigation = new LeftNavigation();
        this.addWest(leftNavigation,12.0);
        rightNavigation = new RightNavigation();
        this.addEast(rightNavigation, 9.0);
        footerPanel = new FooterPanel();
        this.addSouth(footerPanel, 3.5);
        centerPanel = new ContentPanel();
        this.add(centerPanel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you Firebug it? What's the problem? What's your host page's doctype? It should be <!DOCTYPE html>. How are you attaching the DockLayoutPanel? Too many unknowns. Provide more information please.

Comment: We especially need to know how you're adding this display to your project. RootLayoutPanel.get().add, or what?

Comment: Yes, I firebug it and there is not error. html have <!DOCTYPE HTML> and it is added in the RootPanel using RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get("applicationWindow");
  rootPanel.add(applicationWindow);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much Riley for you hint.

Now I changed

```
RootPanel.get().add() --> RootLayoutPanel.get().add()
```

problem solved.